# Cloud Run: Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery duplicate uploads

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run instance that receives list of files from cloud storage, checks if item exists in BigQuery and uploads it if it doesn't exist yet.

The pipeline structure is: Cloud Function (get list of files from GCS) > PubSub > Cloud Run > BigQuery.

I can't tell where the problem lies but I suspect its with PubSub at least once delivery, I've set the Acknowledgement deadline to 300 seconds and Retry Policy to "Retry after exponential backoff delay"

What I expect is to call the Function, get a list of files from GCS, the pipeline gets triggered and I see a 1:1 for files in GCS to BQ.

My question is what GCP services should I be using to get upload json files from GCS to upload to BQ? Dataflow? I ask because this seems to be something between the Cloud Run instances.

Relevant code in Cloud Run instance
Check if file exists

```
def existInTable(table_id, dataId):
    try:
        client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT)
        tableref = PROJECT + "." + table_id
        sql = """
        SELECT version, dataId
        FROM `{}`
        WHERE version LIKE "{}" AND dataId LIKE "{}"
        """.format(tableref,__version__.__version__,dataId)
        query_job = client.query(sql) 
        results = query_job.result()
        print("Found {} Entries for dataid {} and version {} in {}".format(results.total_rows,dataId,__version__.__version__,table_id))
        if results.total_rows>0:
            print("Skip upload")
            return True
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to find entries in table {}".format(table_id))
        print(f"error: {e}")
        return False
```

upload

```
def uploadCloudStorageFileToBigquery(table_id,gcsEntity):
    client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema= getSchema(),
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
    )
    # Report Path
    uri = "gs://{}/{}/{}file.json".format(gcsEntity.bucketName,gcsEntity.version,gcsEntity.dataId)
    # Start upload process
    try:
        load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
            uri,
            table_id,
            location="US",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
            job_config=job_config,
        )  # Make an API request.
        load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
        destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
        print("Successfully uploaded {},{} to {}, {} rows".format(gcsEntity.dataId,gcsEntity.version,table_id,destination_table.num_rows))
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed uploading {},{} to {} \n URI: {} \n".format(gcsEntity.dataId,gcsEntity.version,table_id,uri))
        print(f"error: {e}")
        return False
```

function that ties the two together

```
def runBigQueryUpload(gcsEntity):
    
    # get Name for individual Table
    individualTable = BIGQUERYDATASET + "." + gcsEntity.bucketName.replace("gcsBucket-","")
    # Only continue if no entry exists so far in Individual BigQuery Table 
    noExceptionCaught = True
    if existInTable(individualTable,gcsEntity.dataId):
        print("BQ Instance {} from {} Already exists in {}".format(gcsEntity.dataId,gcsEntity.bucketName,individualTable))
    else:
        try: 
            uploadCloudStorageFileToBigquery(individualTable,gcsEntity)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed upload to BigQuery table {} for {}".format(individualTable,gcsEntity.dataId ))
            print(f"error: {e}")
            noExceptionCaught = False
    # Upload to main table
    if existInTable(BIGQUERYTABLEID,gcsEntity.dataId):
        print("BQ Instance {} from {} Already exists in {}".format(gcsEntity.dataId,gcsEntity.bucketName,individualTable))
    else:
        try: 
            uploadCloudStorageFileToBigquery(BIGQUERYTABLEID,gcsEntity)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed upload to BigQuery table {} for {}".format(individualTable,gcsEntity.dataId ))
            print(f"error: {e}")
            noExceptionCaught = False

    # If any try block failed, return False
    if not noExceptionCaught:
        print("Failed in upload process {} from {}".format(gcsEntity.dataId, gcsEntity.bucketName))
        return 500
    
    return 200
```

Comment: How do you upload the files in Cloud Run? Do you use a load jobs or streaming insert? if streaming, what is the size of each file?

Comment: The first step is to determine if this is a duplicate message issue or a bug in your code/design. Log the **MessageId** and then verify. Messages can be duplicated, so you need a way to duplicate and/or detect that you have already processed the file. Do more debugging and then update your question.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm using a load job but the files are +- 2.6kb.

Comment: @JohnHanley when you say they can be duplicated you mean from PubSub? The bug only occurs when I pass in a list of files. For a single file the program runs without duplicates. But will try and run the program directly without PubSub.

Comment: PubSub is a guaranteed at least once delivery, Which means you might get duplicate messages. This article explains more: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/handling-duplicate-data-in-streaming-pipeline-using-pubsub-dataflow

Comment: Are you 100% positive you are acknowledging the messages within the time limit? Your question does not show how Pub/Sub messages are managed.

Comment: What's your logic when you detect an existing file in BigQuery? Do you sometime return error 4XX or 5XX because you have duplicate file or things like that?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I've added the code, it shouldn't return 500 unless the upload function throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help somebody else...
So I had to rethink the architecture completely.
I had three steps that I needed to do.

1. do some long processing on files (done with PubSub, on a per file basis, in order for Cloud Run to ack back on time).
2. Batch process all files in GCS to BQ in one go using `write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE"`, this overwrites a table and ensured no duplicate entries.
3. Pass a wildcard character in the uri for batch processing multiple files. I called this once entire batch was in GCS.

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        autodetect=True,
        schema= getSchema(),
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    )

uri = "gs://{}/subfolder/*file.json".format(bucketName) #note wildcard

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
            uri,
            tableId,
            location="US",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
            job_config=job_config,

        )  # Make an API request.
```

Notes: old code actually looped through each file in GCS and called `load_table_from_uri` each time (not batch processing and wastes quota).
Turns out two separate Cloud Run instances both checked that a file didn't exist in BQ and both uploaded at the same time (that's why I needed batch processing)